# 170+ columns, count number of rows with repeating (duplicate) data

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I'm looking at a large data set, 170+ columns, 10k rows and want to summarize the data within the table by counting the number of times a certain descriptor is used.

In the example screenshot below, one column contains rows with repetitive information, so I added a value column, set the rows in that column to = 1 and summed this using a pivot table.

However with a much larger data set it isn't efficient to use a pivot table, is there a better way to count the duplicate data in the rows? Power query?

Example Results:

[image]

Comment: Show sample source data and desured result for it. In formatted table form, not as a screenshot.

Comment: There are ways to do this which can involve `VBA` or a long formula, it dependes.

Comment: 1. It isn't clear what you mean by duplicate data. Are you considering each column independently, and looking for values that repeat within that column?  2. Why is a pivot table inefficient?  3. It isn't clear how the example results reflects your description. What values are you summing?  4. With 1.7M cells, what benefit is it to know that there were 6 duplicate values in Customer Price or 6 in Part Number?  It doesn't tell you what values were duplicated, whether 6 values were each duplicated once or 1 value was duplicated 6 times, or where to find those duplicates to do anything about them.

Comment: Please provide more information about your source data.

Comment: Sorry I was not as clear as I should have been. @fixer1234   Q1. Yes, considering each column independently. Q2 Pivot table like the example inefficient because I have to manually select each column in a single pivot table per column. Q3. The values I am summing are entries for each row of that column. Q4. My example was not great. The data set is large and I'm trying to find out if similarities exist from column to column. Basically I'm trying to look at the data to see if I can spot any patterns or identify areas that need to be corrected (data inserted in wrong column. Will post more ^

Comment: "Basically I'm trying to look at the data to see if I can spot any patterns or identify areas that need to be corrected (data inserted in wrong column" I still don't understand what you're trying to DO in a larger sense - but when I have one-offs like what you're describing, one way to immediately notice obvious problems is just to turn on a filter on the whole table, and click into each field's filter dropdown to see if there are values that obviously don't belong.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Power Query for this.  It has an Unpivot feature that can turn columns into rows, with Attribute and Value columns (for the Column Header and cell value). The trick is to use the Advanced option in the Unpivot to avoid aggregating the cell values.

You would need to keep a unique column out of the Unpivot, to preserve the original row counts. Or you could add an Index column to emulate row numbers in Excel.

From there you could use a Pivot Table, or Power Query can Group By and Count.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty clearly the poster wants to count rows in which the entries like "Customer Price" appear. Else the idea of a column of 1's being summed by the pivot table to provide these counts makes no sense.

`COUNTIF` was invented for this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).